# Characteriszation of certain kinds of polynomials

Tags: co.combinatorics, polynomials

My question: 
Is there a known characterization for polynomials $P\in \mathbb{R}[x,y]$
with the property that
$$P(x,y) = 0 \wedge P(y,x) =0 \Rightarrow x = \overline{y}$$
and the number of the solutions to the system is finite?

After a change of variables, one have the equivalent condition for
$Q\in \mathbb{R}[x,y]$ that
$$Q(x,iy) = 0 \wedge Q(x,-iy) =0 \Rightarrow x,y \in \mathbb{R}.$$

This is related to stable polynomials, but not quite.
(There is a nice characterization of real stable polynomials, by Lax).

There exist plenty of such polynomials,
for example, one could construct a series of such polynomials recursively
$$P_n = x P_{n-1} - y P_{n-2}+P_{n-3}$$
with start values $P_0 = 0,P_1 = 0, P_2 = 1.$

This type of polynomials arise naturally from certain determinants of Toeplitz matrices.

EDIT:

Clearly, if $(x,y)$ is a common root,then $(y,x), (\bar{x},\bar{y}), (\bar{y},\bar{x})$
are also roots (by symmetry, and realness of coefficients).

Comment: Are these the same polynomials you asked about at http://mathoverflow.net/questions/78777/characteriszation-of-certain-kinds-of-polynomials ?  

Comment: Yes, I just realized I've asked a related question before.
However, I now have a much larger family, given by different recursions (of different lengths). The one in 78777 is just a special case. Seems like I need to refresh my memory about the answer on the question I asked about 6 months ago...